# set Message Subject for MFMailComposeViewController but don't show it in the navigation bar

Tags: iphone, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

How can i set a subject to a MFMailComposeViewController but do not show the title in the navigation bar?

The thing is that i have a background image and the text overlays on the image and it doesn't look good.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be customizing the interface of the mail composer vc:

From the docs:

> Important: The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application. In addition, after presenting the interface, your application is not allowed to make further changes to the email content. The user may still edit the content using the interface, but programmatic changes are ignored. Thus, you must set the values of content fields before presenting the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link:

http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/changing-the-navigation-bar-with-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller/